# Voluntarily stopping SSDI and still receive Medicare?

Tags: united-states, medicare, disability

I'm helping a friend on SSDI navigate returning to work (as a freelancer) full time, while retaining *some* healthcare-she currently has Medicare because of SSDI (more specifically, Parts A and B and-most importantly-a Part C program where she actually uses).

So I'm reading that while freezing benefits is a thing (straight from SSA right here! https://choosework.ssa.gov/blog/2019-05-02-voluntarily-suspending-your-ssdi-benefits-while-working) What happens to your Medicare benefits while that happens? Like she really wants to just buy an out of pocket policy since she'll be making more than enough as a freelancer, but will voluntarily stopping your SSDI count as a special enrollment? Would she still have Medicare? Will it ever be possible for her to get any health insurance if she pauses her Medicare, or does SSDI freezing perma destroy your ability to get health insurance for the rest of your life?

Comment: ACA enrollment is currently open (until 1/15 IIRC), why does she need special enrollment? In any case, losing coverage counts as a special enrollment event. Quitting a job is also voluntary, how is this different?

Comment: Because navigating the world of the intersection of SSDI and Medicare is extremely frustrating and difficult (especially with the pandemic), and as to this specific question, since I don't think it's permanent (the link it self isn't very clear), I just don't know what would happen?

Comment: Like per that website you suspend your SSDI payments-there's nothing there about how that impacts Medicare, or if that would be a special enrollment qualifying event (since this would be happening after Jan 15).

Comment: **If** it disqualifies her from being eligible for Medicare **then** it is a qualifying event (since she'd be losing existing coverage). Whether or not it disqualifies her - I'd suggest asking someone at SSA.